# Prevent JWPlayer from loading JWPLAYER.SWF multiple times for multiple instances

Tags: swfobject, jwplayer

I am using the [JW Embedder](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference#Variables) with JWPlayer to embed 3 videos on a page. (I'm pretty sure the sitatuion would be the same if using SWFObject to do the embedding.

To my horror (!) when looking in Fiddler I saw 3 downloads (HTTP Status 200) for `jwplayer.swf` which is an unnecessary 200kb.

Obviously what's happening is that the javascript for the embedder just spews out the code to instantiate the flash object and then the browser initiates 3 requests for the 100kb `jwplayer.swf` file.

It isn't clever enough to wait for `jwplayer.swf` to load and then use it for the 2 other players.

How can I make sure that jwplayer.swf is only loaded once.

Answer (score 2):

It is up to the browser to decide how to deal with multiple requests for the same objects. Most browsers will save the assets in a cache and either skip the subsequent requests and serve directly from the cache, or they send a different type of request which checks to see if the content has changed on the server.

Either way, there's no way for the player itself to control this behavior. That said....

If you're down with HTML5, you can try making a cache manifest for the swf.

This script looks promising: http://blog.sebastian-martens.de/2010/05/preload-assets-with-javascript-load-complete-callback-for-single-assets-include-swfflash/ You can preload the first player and then the next two as a post-load callback (See comment 9).